# grouping by non-database field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

How can I group a query result by a field that is not saved in the database.

For example I want to group the result by duration which is came from subtraction of start time and end time.

here is how i find out the duration

```
date1= $row_TicketRS['CloseDate']; 
$date2 = $row_TicketRS['OpenDate'];

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); 

$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));


if ( $days > 0)

{

$time1 = $row_TicketRS['OpenTime'];
$time2= $row_TicketRS['CloseTime'];

$t1=($time1); 
$t2=($time2);

$end=('14:30');
$start=('07:30');

$n = $end- $t1;

$n2 = $t2- $start;

$Hours2 = floor(($n+$n2)+(($days-1)*7));

echo   $Hours2.' Hours';
```

but know i do not know how to add it to the query

here is my query

```
$strQuery = "SELECT count(`ticket`.TicketID) as TotOutput, department.`DeptName` FROM `ticket`, `user`, department where ticket.OwnerID = user.EmpNo and  user.`DepartmentID` = department.`DepartmentID` and OpenDate between'".$DateFrom."' And '".$DateTo."'"
```

Comment: once u get the data from mysql then rest of all is to do with retrieved array, do with php array functions  and create a new array whatever ur need.

Comment: u r doing so long way to calculate hours. this [article](http://forums.webmasterhub.net/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1831) will help u

Comment: thanks dear lol i know its very long way but i take alot of time to figure out that and its working fine now i just want how i can order by duration as you see some of you said to add alias but i do not to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding that computed value to the query with an alias like this:

```
SELECT some_fields, end - start AS duration FROM table ORDER BY duration
```

Comment: Thank you for answer
But the way I calculate the duration is little bit complicated so I don’t not know how to add it the query

Comment: It shouldn't matter. You just need to put the expression there and follow with the AS alias_name_for_the_column and use that in the order by clause.

Comment: It is easy but if you can show your query without any sorting, it would be easier to tell you how to change it.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by that

Comment: If what you need is to sort the query according to some parameters, if you show the original query that does not yet sort the results, we may help you further by understanding your difficulty.

Comment: i add my query in the question

Comment: And what is the expression that the defines the sorting criteria?

Comment: You have 3 solutions: 1) Map those calculations back to an SQL expression, add that expression to a query column and sort by that column, 2) Execute the query, retrieve all the results into an array, perform the calculations for each row, add the result to array as an extra element, use PHP usort function to sort the results by the value of that extra element, 3) add an extra column to your database table, compute the expression for each record of the table and store the result in that column, execute the query sorting by that column.  I recommend the last solution because its more efficient.

Comment: sorry i know l am asking too much but i need to finish this task soon so how i can map calcuations to SQL experssion

Comment: Just use the equivalent expressions in SQL. From what I can see, MySQL can support all the expressions you use in PHP.

Comment: it does not work with me or in other word i do not know how to do that  any way thanks a lot for your help and I really appreciate that 

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better to have details, but a derived table/inline view would allow you to group by a computed value:

```
  SELECT x.duration, 
         COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT t.col, 
                 t.end_time - t.start_time AS duration
            FROM YOUR_TABLE t) x
GROUP BY x.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

dont put alias for hidden column , use directly

exmaple:

```
SELECT id, FLOOR(value/100)
  FROM tbl_name
  GROUP BY id, FLOOR(value/100);
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

> MySQL permits expressions in GROUP BY
>   clauses, so the alias is unnecessary:

Comment: Thank you for answer
But the way I calculate the duration is little bit complicated so I don’t not know how to add it the query

Comment: @Maryan i think u must do it with php [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) and see the example on that page..

Comment: thanks dear i take alot of time to figure out that and its working fine now i just want how i can order by duration as you see some of you said to add alias but i do not to do that